# Flex box how to specify the column for item placement

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, multiple-columns

I have a software which creates the repeatable blocks. They use flexbox. Currently, they align based on the position of the repeatable block, stacked below each item. Say in the image below if the repeatable blocks are item1, item2, item3, item4. It will render the column with the same order.

But I want to allow the user to have a multi-column option. I can use the grid and considering it is something dynamic I cant use that. Say I can assign the `grid-item` property to item 1 as `firstone` and create  `grid-template-areas:"firstone secondone"` but assigning the item2, item3 with `grid-item` `secondone` will have content placed one over each other.

`grid-template-areas:"firstone secondone" "firstone secondone" "firstone secondone"` will do the trick but I don't have a method to generate this CSS there can be more than 4 items.

Any possible solution? Alternatives?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. first item will always be in the first column and rest 3 will be in the second column and if more item comes you want to create more columns with 3 item each. Is this you wanna achieve?

Comment: @TraptiRahangdale. I want a solution where a user decided where the item to be placed. Item1 can go to col2 as well.

Comment: @TraptiRahangdale please check this video https://youtu.be/H0FnQKhOiHk?t=48

Comment: Grid and Flexbox always keen on filling out the empty space. To prevent this you have to explicity tell an item where to go with ´grid-column´ and ´grid-row´

Comment: Create a basic layout first, define grid css using CSS variables. And then on click of  any item change the variable. At least create a basic example this way, then it will be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: @TraptiRahangdale okay I will try. It's a dynamic problem which makes it difficult to explain

Comment: @Effection i think my solution lie there. Checking

Comment: you can use this as reference which i created. https://codepen.io/tripti1410/pen/XWWzdvj?editors=0110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for these problems is the right choice! What you are trying to achieve is a bit more complex than the use case of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

By using `grid-template-columns` instead of `grid-template-areas`, and the `:first-child` selector, it it possible to achieve what you describe.

Given this example HTML:

```html
<div>
  <article>Item 1</article>
  <article>Item 2</article>
  <article>Item 3</article>
  <article>Item 4</article>
</div>
```

You can use this CSS:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

article {
  grid-column: 2;
}

article:first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle to see an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/h9k5x7uf/

If you want to make this more dynamic or server rendered, replace `:first-child` with some helper classes instead.

```
.pull-left { grid-column: 1; }
.pull-right { grid-column: 2; }
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem. Say if set the height:500px; ( i place an image of height 500px in the first ) then the first row will end up having a height of 500px, and other boxed will stack under it. the items in the first column will influence items in the second column. :(

Comment: Ah, I did not know your `Item 1` was required to span across multiple rows! To achieve that, try to add `grid-template-row: 1 / span 3` to Item 1. If `3` is too low, try to increase it.

Comment: I am sorry for that :(. I think my image reference confused you.